# Using the responder chain to see when a subview is added

Tags: ios, uiview, event-bubbling, responder-chain

It there any way for a window to tell that a subview's subview has been added. It seems like there is architecture in place (in the form of the responder chain) to allow a kind of event bubbling up the view hierachy, but this only seems to exist to handle user interaction.Does a UIView emit any kind of Event when added to its superview? Is there a way for a window to know when a subview has been added somewhere within its descendent view hierachy?

Answer (score 0):

[-[UIView didMoveToSuperview]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/didMoveToSuperview) tells the view that its superview changed.